# Помогите разместить блоки div. Налезают друг на друга?

Tags: html, css

при float:left на sidebar слайдер налезает на меню и на весь блок. Почему он не отталкивается от sidebar ? Как правильно задать css ?

```
 <div class="sidebar-slider">
        <div class="sidebar">
        Менюшка слева
        </div>
        <div class="slider">
        Слайдер справа
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS

```
.sidebar-slider {display: flex;}
```

Comment: Спасибо, то что нужно )

Comment: А как теперь sidebar задать ширину ? потому что слайдер щимит его. Не могу задать ему ширину!

Comment: @CoffeeKyiv попробуйте задать ширину и для `.slider`

Comment: Например `calc(100% - ширина sidebar)`